# Ask to rename a misspelled tag [td-engine]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I'm DevRel from TDengine. And I found there're hundreds of questions about TDengine tagged by [td-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/td-engine).

Because TDengine is our registered trademark and "td-engine" is a common misspelling, I hope I cloud ask a moderator to rename tag [td-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/td-engine) to [tdengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tdengine).

Comment: What is "DevRel"? Vice President of Developer Relations? Developer Relations Representative? Assistant Manager of Developer Relations? Developer Relations Engineer? Development Assistant Manager? Developer Relations Engineering Manager?

Comment: I just assumed it was their name, @PeterMortensen :-)

Comment: Yes, Vice President of Developer Relations

Answer (score 4):

Sure thing! I've done it now. Should be live; if not, [you know what to blame](https://shouldiblamecaching.com).

[tdengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tdengine) is the primary tag, and [td-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/td-engine) remaps to it (as a synonym, so bookmarks keep working without disruption).